# How to calibrate battery on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: battery

there is no option to disable "when power is critically low" power off, and i heard it should be disabled to be able to consume all the battery power.
has anyone solved this issue ?

Comment: So what do you want to know? How you can switch off the automatic shutdown on low battery power?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the battery until last drop, also if there is anything else i need to do to calibrate properly.